# Date format error while saving in the database

Tags: php, json, mysqli, format

I am trying to store the date in the database using that I received from an ajax post request. The post request is successful and the date received is in the right format. 
The Network Tab in the Console shows that the Format Data for the dates when posted :

```
     start:Mon Mar 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000
     end:Thu Mar 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000
```

However when I save it in the database using the following php code it saves only on today's date :

```
  $json_array["start"]=json_decode($_POST["start"], true);
  $json_array["end"]=json_decode($_POST["end"], true);

  $start = new DateTime($json_array['start']);
  $end = new DateTime($json_array['end']);

  $start =$start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $end =$end->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

And When I use this, it saves it in 31st Dec 1969 7pm:

```
   $json_array["start"]=json_decode($_POST["start"], true);
   $json_array["end"]=json_decode($_POST["end"], true);
   $start =date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$json_array["start"]);
   $end =date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$json_array["end"]);
```

Can Anyone guide me where I am wrong, I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: I don't see the json you are trying to decode? isn't that just a simple string in `$_POST['start']`?

Comment: Perfect Jeff....That was it !

Comment: Make it an answer and I will mark it...That was it, that I was doing wrong all the time...

Comment: Is the post data actually encoded as json?

Comment: glad I could help! Next time: outputting what you actually get could give you a useful hint. I'm actually curious now what json_decode made out of the string...null? undefined? The 31st of December 7pm must be 1.1.1970 00:00UTC in your timezone, right?

Comment: It decoded it and converted it to the present date. For eg when it would print 13 March 2016.
I just did not know why it was doing that until you pointed out that it is already a string. Silly me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the posted data is a json, rather just a simple string.
(and your comment tells me I'm right)

So remove json_decode

```
$json_array["start"]=json_decode($_POST["start"], true);
$json_array["end"]=json_decode($_POST["end"], true);
```

and change the following lines to

```
$start = new DateTime($_POST['start']);
$end = new DateTime($_POST['end']);
```

and you should be fine!

*Of course you should check first what's in that POST and check for errors, isset() aso..... in real life code*